# MS-SQL - Select Non-overlapping integer ranges

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, numbers, range

I have a table containing a bunch of number ranges, something like:

**ID START END**
1 1200 1500
2 1450 1700
3 1800 2100
4 2500 3000
5 2900 3300

What I want to be able to do is select only the non-overlapping ranges from this set (so, for example **1,3 and 4**, or **1,3 and 5**). In addition, I must be able to specify an additional 'padding' value (like a break) that can be variable. So for instance, after selecting ID=1, I may wish to add 400 to end value (going from 1500 to 1900), thus making ID=3 also not available if ID=1 is part of the set of selected ranges.

I've had a look at no less than 7-9 SO posts and they all seem fairly close to what I need, but not quite that. I found one that can find the overlapping ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM TEMP_Times a
JOIN TEMP_Times b on a.TimeStart <= b.TimeEnd
and a.TimeEnd >= b.TimeStart
and a.TimeID <> b.TimeID;
```

But I am failing into converting this into what I need instead. If recursion will be needed that is fine; at most I'll have to grab 10-12 records at a time.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the expected results of such a query would be. As you noted, both (1,3,4) and (1,3,5) satisfy the conditions you've laid out. So do (2,3,4), (2,3,5), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), and (3,5). Any single row also works. What would make any one of these solutions better than the others?

Comment: The expected results are needed to get a list of to-from times (the values are integers, but only for speedier processing - they represent a date and a time) that I can book equipment in to.The break is sometimes needed to repair or refurbish a given item. But what I get is a long list of from-until values which to a large degree overlap; sometimes a few minutes, sometimes hours) and so I need to filter out a list that is fully 'clean'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `NOT EXISTS` can simplify your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Test a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @Test b
    WHERE a.TimeStart <= b.TimeEnd AND a.TimeEnd >= b.TimeStart 
        AND a.TimeStart >= b.TimeStart
        AND a.TimeID <> b.TimeID
)
```

Solution based on window function:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        MaxEnd = MAX(TimeEnd) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStart ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    FROM @Test
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE MaxEnd IS NULL OR TimeStart > MaxEnd
```

Comment: I don't think it's an correct answer. For example, I add a new row (6,1,1000000), you could imagine your result.

Comment: It will return single row (6,1,1000000). What's wrong? If you sort by TimeStart it will be a first value

Comment: In this case 3 rows with id 1,3,4 is still an expected result.

Comment: It depends sort order when you selecting ranges. You assume this is TimeID, but I assume it's a TimeStart. however it's not important: `a.TimeStart >= b.TimeStart`can be replaced with `a.TimeID >= b.TimeID`

Comment: In my second solution this is specified explicitly: `OVER (ORDER BY TimeStart ` (You can write `OVER (ORDER BY TimeID` to receive result that @TriV expects)

Comment: Took me a moment to understand what you're doing here (ok, I kind of still don't, need to read more about it all) but I can say that this does exactly what I need. Thank you Mikhail!